# boost r-tree error: The first type of std::pair has to be an Indexable. How do I fix this?

Tags: c++, boost, eigen, boost-geometry, r-tree

I'm using `boost::geometry::index::rtree` with the point type given by `Eigen::Vector`. To do this, I'm declaring

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace geometry
    {
        namespace traits
        {
            template<typename T, std::size_t D> struct tag<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> { using type = point_tag; };
            template<typename T, std::size_t D> struct dimension<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> : boost::mpl::int_<D> {};
            template<typename T, std::size_t D> struct coordinate_type<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> { using type = T; };
            template<typename T, std::size_t D> struct coordinate_system<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> { using type = boost::geometry::cs::cartesian; };

            template<typename T, std::size_t D, std::size_t Index>
            struct access<Eigen::Vector<T, D>, Index>
            {
                static_assert(Index < D, "out of range");

                using Point = Eigen::Vector<T, D>;
                using CoordinateType = typename coordinate_type<Point>::type;
                static inline CoordinateType get(Point const& p) { return p[Index]; }
                static inline void set(Point& p, CoordinateType const& value) { p[Index] = value; }
            };
        } // namespace traits
    } // namespace geometry
} // namespace boost
```

Then I declare

```
template<class PointType>
using rtree = boost::geometry::index::rtree<PointType, boost::geometry::index::rstar<16>>;
```

and `rtree<std::pair<Eigen::Vector<double, 2>, std::size_t>> foo;`. While this perfectly compiles using MSVC, I'm receiving the error

> error: static assertion failed: The first type of std::pair has to be
> an Indexable.    24 |
> static_assert(boost::geometry::detail::static_assert_check<(CHECK),
> **VA_ARGS**>::value, MESSAGE)

when I compile it under Linux/GCC. What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please make the code self-contained. The snippets provided cannot possibly compile, and people don't love finding out what version of eigen contains those types in what headers again.

Comment: Here's what I made, in case anyone else wants a look https://godbolt.org/z/vfbqY8YbM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow, GCC doesn't match the partial template specialization unless you make `std::size_t D` template parameter `int`.

This probably has to do with an internal interpretation of narrowing restrictions, but I feel it might have been a bug (in some version(s) of GCC?). Clang 15 accepts it just like you report MSVC did.

Changing that fixes it on my GCC versions as well:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/nKq5r587e)**

```
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/std_array.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

namespace boost::geometry::traits {
    template <typename T, int D> struct tag<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> {
        using type = point_tag;
    };
    template <typename T, int D> struct dimension<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> : boost::mpl::int_<D> {};
    template <typename T, int D> struct coordinate_type<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> {
        using type = T;
    };
    template <typename T, int D> struct coordinate_system<Eigen::Vector<T, D>> {
        using type = boost::geometry::cs::cartesian;
    };

    template <typename T, int D, std::size_t Index> struct access<Eigen::Vector<T, D>, Index> {
        static_assert(Index < D, "out of range");

        using Point          = Eigen::Vector<T, D>;
        using CoordinateType = typename coordinate_type<Point>::type;
        static inline CoordinateType get(Point const& p) { return p[Index]; }
        static inline void           set(Point& p, CoordinateType const& value) { p[Index] = value; }
    };
} // namespace boost::geometry::traits

int main() {//
    using Point = Eigen::Vector<double, 2>;
    bgi::rtree<std::pair<Point, std::size_t>, bgi::rstar<16>> foo;
}
```